# SDK to support diff spring version

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, middleware

Assume that I'm planning to develop a SDK, and this SDK is supposed to support different spring version,E.g spring 2.x, spring 3.x and spring 4.x, there are only few dependencies in the SDK,

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

one approach is set ${spring.version} different version, but this will result in lots of costs for maintenance.
any idea about this question?

Comment: @Blobonat see the title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are going to use just a few classes and the methods with the same signature across all spring versions, I recommend you take a look on the [Understanding Maven Version Numbers](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1212/core/MAVEN/maven_version.htm#MAVEN402) specifically on the table **Table 7-1 Version Range References**. Just as an example, when you see the version [1.2,1.3] means 1.2 <= x <= 1.3.

For your case you have to adjust the property "spring.version" to:

```xml
<properties>
    <spring.version>[2.0,4.3]</spring.version>
</properties>
```

Comment: @lawrence I hope it works for you, in my tests is working fine. BTW, [the common way of recognizing a good answer is upvoting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting) ;)

Comment: @Welliington Souza, I'm testing on this idea. That's why I did not upvote this post. I'll vote it after the testing.

Comment: @Welliington Souza， after testing,I found that the project only gets the latest version dependency, also, the project will download all the dependencies between the version range. It cannot get corresponding version when using in different specific spring version. Still, not a good solution to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 1):

First, avoid as much of the Spring dependencies as you can; for example, it's frequently only necessary to include `spring-context` for the `@Component` annotation. Assuming you can avoid forward incompatibility, simply build against the earliest compatible Spring. Components compiled for Spring 3.2, for example, will often load with no problem in Spring 4.3.

However, if it's necessary to use features from a new Spring version, the best approach is to create a new artifact entirely. For example, when Thymeleaf needed to use features added only in Spring 4, [it split into `thymeleaf-spring3` and `thymeleaf-spring4`](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/thymeleafspring.html). This does require a little bit more effort on your part but will make builds and transitions smoother for all your users.

Comment: to my understanding, I have to supply with different version SDK for different spring version! right?

Comment: @lawrence If your SDK isn't forward-compatible with the Spring versions (e.g., uses a deprecated API that's removed). Something simple will probably translate with minimal issues.'